# Python Selenium accepting the "Before you continue" form on google maps in GoogleChrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, google-maps

Yesterday I started to change my code a little.
One part apparently was very tricky.
Its only use was to click on the continue button so the next click on the car symbol won't raise an error for. As I learned the error is raised because the form is in front of the button. (Apparently it sometimes works nevertheless)
This code snipped worked perfectly,
but changing it resulted in some errors I didn't see coming.
This code should work for itself if anyone wants to test it.
The variables *_strasse, (street name '+' separated)
*_hausnummer, (House number)
*_plz, (Post Code)
*_stadt (city) worked for me.

```py
try:
    #Getting the HTML
    link = f"https://www.google.de/maps/dir/{start_strasse}+{start_hausnummer},+{start_plz}+{start_stadt},+Deutschland/{end_strasse}+{end_hausnummer},+D-{end_plz}+{end_stadt},+Deutschland"
    driver.get(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    #Wait for the button to appear
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]').click()
    except :
        continue
    #Find the button for routes by car
    list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('jstcache') == '508', driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')))[0].click()
    #Parse the fastest times
    times = [ re.findall(r'[0-9]+', x.text[:-3]) for x in  list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('jstcache') == '265', driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')))]
    print('Elemente:', times )
    #Select the fastest time
    length = times[0][0]
    #Convert hh:mm format to minutes
    length = int(length[0]) if len(length) == 1 else 60*int(length[0]) + int(length[1])
    print(length)
except:
    #used for debugging
    #print(str(runde) + f'/{len(adresses.keys())}', link)
    raise
```

My new code looks like this, but it's not able to find the continue button by XPATH.

```py
try:
    link = f"https://www.google.de/maps/dir/{start_strasse}+{start_hausnummer},+{start_plz}+{start_stadt},+Deutschland/{end_strasse}+{end_hausnummer},+D-{end_plz}+{end_stadt},+Deutschland"
    driver.get(link)

    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]').click()
    #element = driver.find_element_by_css('div[class*="U26fgb"]')
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    #list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('jstcache') == '508', driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')))[0].click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@jstcache='508']").click()
    #times = [ re.findall(r'[0-9]+', x.text[:-3]) for x in  list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('jstcache') == '265', driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')))]
    #print('Elemente:', times )
    #length = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute('jstcache') == '265', driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')))[0].text[:-3])
    #length = times[0][0]
    
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@jstcache='265']")
    zeit = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', elem.text[:-3])
    length = int(zeit[0]) if len(zeit) == 1 else 60*int(zeit[0]) + int(zeit[1])
    verbindung = ','.join([start, end, str(length)]) + '\n'
    datei.write(verbindung)
    print(verbindung)
except:
    print(link)
    raise
```

I tested countless ideas from the web including invoking some java script functions instead of clicking, switching to an iframe, or to the active element or the active alert.
I think one of the ideas was actually right but I implemented it wrong.
Apparently implicit waits worked way better for me than any wait until what I found strange.
So I thought that my code could already have the problem inside.

I appreciate all help and comments!
It's my first post here so if I missed something pls tell me!
[How the Browser looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3Jcm.png)
[The HTML of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEUZo.png)

Comment: Can you provide the exact link you are trying out? Also which button exactly are you trying to click? Screenshot or something would help

Comment: I'm trying a bunch of links like:
[link](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/Kurzebracker+Weg+40,+13503+Berlin,+Deutschland/Tietzenweg+101,+D-12203+Berlin,+Deutschland)
[link](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/Kurzebracker+Weg+40,+13503+Berlin,+Deutschland/Radickestraße+43,+D-12489+Berlin,+Deutschland)
[link](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/Kurzebracker+Weg+40,+13503+Berlin,+Deutschland/Britzer+Damm+164,+D-12347+Berlin,+Deutschland)
I'm trying to click on the "continue"-button in the form.
I will add a picture of it too.